# As the limit of $n$ goes to infinity, prove that $x^n=0$ if $|x|<1$ using delta-epsilon definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, epsilon-delta

There is another post showing a different solution to this problem, but I wanted to try using the delta-epsilon definition to show that as $n$ tends to infinity, $x^n$ converges to $0$ for $|x| < 1$. Please correct or suggest correction -

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given, and let $\delta = \min \{ \epsilon^{1/n}, 1 \}$

Then

$|x^n - 0| = |x^n| = |x|^n < \delta^n <= (\epsilon^{1/n})^n = \epsilon$

My apologies on the formatting. To be clear above, I'm referring the nth-root of epsilon whenever appropriate.

Comment: $\delta <1$ is not necessary. You can take $\delta=\epsilon^{1/n}$.

Comment: If you're trying to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=0$, then this argument doesn't work because your choice of $\delta$ doesn't say anything about how big $n$ needs to be for $|x^n-0|<\varepsilon$ to be true. The only thing you've shown is that if $x$ is a real number with $|x|<\delta$, then $|x^n-0|<\varepsilon$, proving that $\lim_{x\to 0}x^n=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Alann Rosas points out in the comments, there's a big problem with your proof, and it is not to do with the $\delta < 1$. The issue is that you are actually showing $\lim_{x \to 0} x^n = 0$, not $\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n = 0$. To show the latter, you need to use the $\varepsilon$-$N$ definition of a limit. That is, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there would have to exist some $N$ such that
$$n > N \implies |x^n| < \varepsilon.$$
There's a kind of "obvious" way of proceeding here: take the natural logarithm of both sides of $|x^n| < \varepsilon$ to get the equivalent inequality:
$$n \ln |x| < \ln \varepsilon \iff n > \frac{\ln \varepsilon}{\ln |x|}.$$
(Note: $\ln|x| < 0$ as $|x| < 1$.)

The "obvious" way has a very subtle pitfall here, to do with the definition of the logarithm. It depends how the logarithm is specifically defined (there are several equivalent definitions), but often the fact that $x^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ is used somewhere in the construction of the logarithm. In many treatments of real analysis, this makes the proof lamentably circular!

Fortunately, there is another proof that avoids this pitfall, and it's not too bad. If we consider the sequence $a_n = |x|^n$, then we can represent it as a recurrence relation:
$$a_{n+1} = |x|a_n, \quad a_0 = 1.$$
Because $0 < |x| < 1$, we have $0 < a_{n+1} < a_n$, just by the usual ordered field axioms. This makes $a_n$ both bounded below by $0$ and monotone decreasing, so the monotone convergence theorem proves that a limit $L$ does exist. If we take the limit of both sides of the recurrence relation, we get
$$L = |x|L \implies L(1 - |x|) = 0 \implies L = 0,$$
as $1 - |x| \neq 0$. This proves the limit is $0$, as required.

Comment: Excellent explanation!

Comment: @AlannRosas Thanks!

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you for the detailed, illuminating response! My goal is more to learn rather than just solve problems, so I appreciate the additional detail.

Comment: @user2192320 You're welcome! That aligns nicely with my personal goals on this site too, so that's good. :-)

Comment: @TheoBendit You mentioned that the obvious path of using the logarithm to determine the delta value had a somewhat subtle flaw. Could you please elaborate on this a little? For interest and understanding.

Comment: @user2192320 The issue is, as I mentioned, is with the definition of the logarithm, and there are many definitions that authors use. Many of them rely on convergence of geometric series, which in turn relies on $x^n \to 0$. For example, if you define $\exp(x) = \sum x^n/n!$ and $\ln$ as its inverse, then how do you know the series even converges? You can't use Taylor's theorem or MVT, because we don't yet have a function, let alone a differentiable one, to apply them to. It does depend on what definition you use, but logarithms are surprisingly heavy machinery, so it's better not to use them.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you so much for the response! I appreciate the additional insight; the comments are gold.